# s3 object not looping as expecting

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Bash script was working before
Below script broke after a clean install
AWS Command Line Interface is installed and AWS is configured

When is it not looping through each file?

```
## variables are set before this point
files=$(/usr/local/bin/aws s3api list-objects --bucket "$bucket" --prefix "$target_zipname" --query "Contents[].{Key: Key}")

##return sample##
# [ { "Key": "fmpbks_2016_08_18_17_08_35.zip" }, { "Key": "fmpbks_2016_08_18_17_14_39.zip" }, { "Key": "fmpbks_2016_08_19_10_54_24.zip" }, { "Key": "fmpbks_2016_08_19_10_55_57.zip" }, { "Key": "fmpbks_2016_08_19_10_56_29.zip" }, { "Key": "fmpbks_2016_08_19_11_00_56.zip" } ]
##
for zip_file in $files
do
echo $zip_file # for testing
delete_path="s3://$bucket/$zip_file"
deleted=$(/usr/local/bin/aws s3 rm $delete_path)
break
done
```

output:

```
[
{
"Key":
"fmpbks_2016_08_18_17_08_35.zip"
},
{
"Key":
"fmpbks_2016_08_18_17_14_39.zip"
},
{
"Key":
"fmpbks_2016_08_19_10_54_24.zip"
},
{
"Key":
"fmpbks_2016_08_19_10_55_57.zip"
},
{
"Key":
"fmpbks_2016_08_19_10_56_29.zip"
},
{
"Key":
"fmpbks_2016_08_19_11_00_56.zip"
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `aws s3api list-buckets` command returns a **JSON object** by default. The `for` loop doesn't understand how to interpret JSON.

Use the `--output text` option to list each file on a separate line:

```
files=$(aws s3api list-objects --bucket MY-BUCKET --query 'Contents[*].Key' --output text)
```

By the way, if your goal is to **delete all files within a certain path**, you could use:

```
aws s3 rm s3://MY-BUCKET --exclude "*" --include "MY-PREFIX*" --recursive
```

Comment: Many thanks that solve it. This is a backup system where I zip a directory everyday and move the file to amazon but only want a max of 3 backups. And it is working thanks to your answer.

Comment: Great! If you're looking for a backup tool, I like using [Cloudberry Backup](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/cloud-backup-windows-desktop.aspx). It is now available as Freeware, too.